# Wireless connection error on windows xp professional

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-xp

I have windows xp professional. I installed and afterwards updated all network drivers but i still cannot connect to wifi (Ethernet works). Is there any way to solve this? Is there some problem with drivers itself, but when i updated them they remained same, that means that they are the one needed for wifi connection to be possible. Maybe I didn't install all drivers that are needed for wireless connection. Can someone give me a list all of them?

Comment: You need to disclose make and model information... Otherwise, "*Is there any way to solve this*" ..... yes, there is a way to solve this... let me know if that helps!!

Answer (score 0):

I have HP 530(Windows xp professional version 2002 service pack 3).

When I go to Network adapters this is what write there:

- Broadcom 802.11 b/g WLAN
- INTEL(R) PRO/100 VE Network Connection

When I try to connect to internet only thing that works is ethernet. And I can't connect wirelessly. It can't even see any wifi network in range(on the list of wireless networks, even when I refresh it).